# Why does SUM convert my expression to something less precise?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Consider the following two queries:

```
SELECT 
SUM(val)/convert(decimal(38),42) b
FROM (SELECT 62.13 val) t 

SELECT 
val/convert(decimal(38),42) b
FROM (SELECT 62.13 val) t
```

The results are

```
1.479285
```

and

```
1.479285714285714285714285714285714285
```

respectively.

The docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810(v=sql.110).aspx say that the first expression should be a decimal(38,s) shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for the first *part* of the first query, we get a `decimal(38,s)` (in this case, `s` will be 2). But then we have a division - so we need to consider what happens with precision and scale when [division occurs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)

Operation:

> e1 / e2

Precision:

> p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)

Scale:

> max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)

So the result of the division, we get a precision of 38 - 0 + 2 + max(6,2+38+1) = 81. 81!. And the scale will be max(6,2+38+1) = 39. But you cannot have a `decimal(81,39)`. So we have:

> The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.

Comment: This is a kick-ass answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` is respecting val's datatype, which is not `DECIMAL(38,36)` like you seem to be looking for. If you use `CONVERT` to explicitly set val's datatype in the substatement where it's generated, it will be inherited by SUM. I.E:

```
SELECT 
SUM(val)/convert(decimal(38),42) b
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,36), 62.13) val) t
```

Or you could tack on sufficient significant zeros (34 of them, or "62.130000000000000000000000000000000000") to the end of the literal to demonstrate to TSQL how many significant digits right of the dot that you care about in the datatype.

Comment: Thanks Keseph, This was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Second query explains this:

```
DECLARE @what sql_variant

SELECT @what = 62.13
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'BaseType'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Precision'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Scale')

SELECT @what = SUM(62.13)
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'BaseType'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Precision'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Scale')

SELECT @what = SUM(val)/convert(decimal(38),42) FROM (SELECT 62.13 val) t
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'BaseType'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Precision'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Scale')

SELECT @what = val/convert(decimal(38),42) FROM (SELECT 62.13 val) t 
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'BaseType'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Precision'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Scale')
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're getting at here Dd2. I can see from your query that the precision is there, but the scale is different.